# Adding additional data to an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, attr-accessor

I'm retrieving a "Widget" ActiveRecord object:

```
@widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
```

I want to add some extra data to it before I return it, so I'm adding it using:

```
@widget.display_name = "test display name"
```

I can then do `puts @widget.display_name` and this indeed does display "test display name", but when I call `puts @widget.inspect` it does not include the extra data.

I was originally getting:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `display_name=' for # <Widget:0x007fe6147e8e00>):
```

but I included `attr_accessor :display_name` on the Widget model and that stopped that particular message.

Just to be clear, I don't actually want to store this extra data in the database, but rather just return it as a JSON object. I'm rendering the JSON using `render json: @widget, status: :ok` and this is also not including the extra data.

For clarity, here is my code:

```
def show
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    @widget.display_name = "test display name"
    puts @widget.display_name # displays "test display name"
    puts @widget.inspect
    if @widget
      render json: @widget, status: :ok
    else
      head :not_found
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try merging the `display_name` into `@widget`'s attributes:

```
@widget = @widget.attributes.merge(display_name: "test display name")
render json @widget
```

The above should return a JSON object of `@widget`'s attributes, including the specified display_name.

Hope it helps!